# What is 'Copy' option while viewing email attached documents

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, email, attachment

I would like to know about the 'Copy' option/action available while viewing the documents attached in the email. I am referring to the default 'Email' app present on the iOS devices.

Following are more specific questions:

1. What does the Copy action copy? A complete document or part of it?
2. Where does the Paste action come in picture for the copied action in email viewer?

This is the screenshot:

[image: Viewing attached document in email using native email app]

Answer (score 1):

I've been checking, searching and researching around this question about `.PDF` files for the past half an hour, but not finding any answer to that file type. However since you haven't asked about PDF files specifically, I'm putting my answer here.

The ***Copy*** option is not available for all file types attached to an email; for example a `.zip` file or even a `.txt` or `.doc` file does not have this option. Video files also come with a different option called ***Save Video***.

So, this option seems to be available for image and PDF files only. If you copy an image file using that option, and then compose a new mail, you can simply paste it by long-tapping the email body section and select *paste* option.

[image]

And that will insert the copied image in-line into your mail which does not work with PDF files. You can copy them, there's no place to paste them. The same paste option wouldn't show up after copying a PDF file. I'd say this is another iOS bug/future-feature that Apple is trying to include in later versions, as file attachments have always been a problem even after almost 8 versions and 8 years.

Log a bug and report this if you have a developer account.